# How does air resist a piston?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, acoustics, flow

[image: Problem statement]

The pipe is long, so the moving air never gets to circulate with the outside air. The piston starts off in the middle of the pipe, so it's pushing the air in front of it and pulling the air behind it. There is a high pressure wave moving ahead, and a low pressure wave moving behind both at at Mach 1.0 in opposite directions. So the amount of air being accelerated increases with time.

We'll have to introduce $\rho$, the density of air at NTP and some mechanics $F = M  a$ and a bit of calculus.

I'm pretty sure that the force required to keep the piston increases indefinitely, and I suspect at an exponential rate, and I'd love to see the maths. My degree in mathematical physics was awarded 60 years ago and is no longer up to the task.

Eventually I want to understand how the force is affected by changing the length of the pipe, by varying its length from a fixed value through extending at the speed of the piston, through to extending at Mach 1.0 (which I suspect will be the same as the "long" pipe).

I am trying to put some maths to my paper "Origins of the pressure variations around a sail" at https://gpsanimator.com/swept_volume_theory.

There's also a nifty video at https://youtu.be/dgE9xhIjTOU with a link to the paper in the description.

Comment: It seems that there are multiple questions in one: you first state idealized conditions (pipe is infinitely long), and want general description for this case... but then you want to see what happens when these idealized conditions do not apply.

Comment: No, I am initially interested in the long pipe configuration. The variations to the pipe length are are a secondary isue.

Answer (score 2):

We limit ourselves to an infinite pipe and to largely subsonic displacement of the piston: $v \ll c$. The movement of the piston is denoted $A(t)$.
As we follow the piston over time, it is natural to adopt a Lagrangian description. So $\xi(x,t)$ is the displacement at $t$ of the slice which was **at rest** at $x$.

The general solution of the problem is the sum of two traveling waves of opposite directions but here, it is natural to restrict oneself to a single traveling wave propagating in the direction of increasing $x$: $$\xi(x,t)=f (t-x/c)$$

The boundary condition $\xi(0,t)=A(t)$ gives $f=A$. Finally, we find $$\xi(x,t)=A(t-x/c)$$ with $A(t)$ the displacement of the piston. In your case, $A(t)=0$ if $t<0$ and $A(t)=v(t-\tau)$ if $t>\tau$. ($\tau$ is the time during which the piston starts moving).

In conclusion: a sound wave propagates in front of the piston at the speed $c$. Behind this wave front, the fluid in front of the piston is moving at speed $v$. In front of the wave front, the fluid is at rest : it does not yet know that the piston is in motion.

For a progressive wave, there is a simple relationship between the overpressure and the velocity $p=\rho c v$: the overpressure in front of the piston is therefore constant and the force $F=pS$ too. The power provided by the operator $Fv$ is used to give kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2} \rho c v^2$ (per unit volume) and potential energy to the gas which takes the speed $v$ (equal to the kinetic energy for a traveling wave) . We verify that $P=Fv=S \rho c v^2$

**EDIT : supersonic piston**

I have find a link which can help you : [Shock wave generated by a moving piston](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluidhtml/node200.html)

I admit the results of this link. The author define :

$$ Ma_p= \frac{v_p}{ c_1 }$$ with $c_1$ the speed of sound in the unperturbed gaz and $\beta=\frac{p_2-p_1}{p_1}$
When you know the piston velocity, you can compute $ Ma_p= \frac{v_p }{c_1 }$. The pressure $p_2$ is what you are looking for in your problem. The force is $F=(p_2-p_1)S$. Since $p_1$ is the atmospheric pressure, you know $p_2$ when you know $\beta$.

You have a simple equation for $\beta$ :

$$\frac{1}{(Ma_p^2) \beta^2}=\frac{1}{\beta^2}+\frac{\gamma +1}{2 \gamma \beta}$$

Solving this equation, you are able to find $p_2$ and the force, which is constant again in this case. The author give two approximate formula in the case of a weak shock and of a strong shock.

In particular, in the case of a weak shock, we have simply  $\beta=\gamma Ma_p$ or $$(p_2-p_1)=\gamma p_1 \frac{v_p}{ c_1 }$$
But, since $c_1^2=\gamma \frac{p_1}{\rho_1}$ we find $$(p_2-p_1)=\rho_1 c_1 v_p$$ As predicted by the linear theory !

Note that the mathematics seem simpler because we are in steady state and we are not studying the generation phase of the shock wave.

**EDIT n°2 : trying to explain why it is reasonable to have a uniform pressure and velocity between the piston and the wave front**

I think your intuition is not correct. Maybe the following image could make you change your mind: Imagine that we push the piston and that we stop it a little later. A sound wave slice of finite width will propagate. Within this slice, the fluid is compressed and has the speed of the piston. Depending on the speed with which one accelerates or brakes, there will be more or less wide transition zones in front and behind the edge.

Now, imagine that we make a succession of piston movements, you will have a succession of slices which follow one another. Within each slice, the fluid is compressed and goes at the speed of the piston.

By passing to the limit, you arrive at the continuous movement of the piston: it constantly generates new waves which follow the previous ones. It is therefore reasonable to consider that the pressure is uniform in the area between the piston and the wavefront.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Can you break that down a bit please? I faltered at "( is the time during which the piston starts moving)". Since the piston is "light" it can start at it's velocity . Why is it a requirement that  ≪ ? 

 .

Comment: Sorry, I was interrupted while editing. Can you break that down a bit please? 1) I faltered at "( is the time during which the piston starts moving)". Since the piston is "light" it can start at it's velocity . 2) Why is it a requirement that  ≪ ? That wasn't part of my problem statement ,  could be /2. 3) How do you derive  "=" and 4) what is S in " ="? =

Comment: If the velocity $v$ is close to $c$, the problem is clearly more complex because we are no longer in the domain of linear acoustics. A shock wave will form. The relation between $p$ and $v$ is valid for a traveling wave in linear acoustics. $S$ is the area of ​​the piston. You can take $\tau$ null if it accelerates very quickly.

Comment: Whether the wave is a shock wave or a pressure wave, it seems certain that a wave will form. In my scenario the velocity of the piston through the tube could be any speed up to c, so limiting the solution to v <<c is not within my problem statement.

Comment: The solution to your problem for any speed exists but it would take too long for me to develop it. Interestingly, this is the problem that Hugoniot already posed in 1889. On the wikipedia site "Rankine–Hugoniot conditions", you will find in note 2 a link to the original article by Hugoniot (part 2). The math is a bit more complicated than for linear waves (Riemann characteristics)

Comment: I don't think it is quite the Rankine–Hugoniot situation described in Wikipedia because the diagram appears to describe the densities either side of the shockwave as uniform, ρ1 and ρ2. In my piston system, whilst ρ2 may be uniform, the density in Region 1 will not be uniform. It will vary from the piston to the position of the  pressure wave with the pressure and temperature of the fluid.    I wonder why you say the solution to my problem would take too long. Do you have a strategy? Please elaborate.

Comment: I have added some results for the supersonic case. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Many thanks for your continued attention to this issue. I followed the link to  "Piston-Generated Shock Wave" but find the same problem as I found in the Rankine–Hugoniot Wiki paper: "In region 2 , which lies between the piston and the shock wave ..., the gas is co-moving with the piston, so its velocity is $ u_2=V_p$ ." The gas in this region cannot be regarded as having a single velocity. It is a continuum under change, it is not a solid object or a homogenous continuum. It makes no sense. And thanks but I am absolutely not interested in supersonic pistons!

Comment: I have added a new edit trying to convince you that it is reasonable to assume a uniform pressure and velocity between the piston and the front wave.

Comment: Your English is excellent. Maybe, while you're editing your original comment you could delete the section on supersonic pistons. That really does muddy the water. The piston in my problem is not supersonic. I'll respond to your Note 2 below.

Comment: The over-pressure at the front of the piston is simply the dynamic pressure of air at speed u, and the under-pressure at the rear is the same, so the total pressure on the piston is ρu^2. I still think the pressure (and density) of the air between the piston and the wave front, but it's no important. The force required to keep the 1 m^r piston travelling is

Answer (score 0):

I have *an answer*, but it raises some further troubling questions. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FaVQGHtRbzVueoNYdCms34TMoe6iHtDhIK-BaE7_ZK4/edit?usp=sharing
It generates a realistic relationship between the speed of the piston and the force required:
[image: relationship between the speed of the piston and the force required]
However, I am aware that the algorithm relies on an invalid premise: that, in the instantaneous snapshot of the system S2, the pressure p, density ρ and temperature K of the air between the piston and the pressure front is homogenous.

I am pretty sure that in the dynamic situation these properties will vary smoothly between a high value at the piston, and approaching asymptotically to the ambient values at the pressure front as indicated below.
[image]
My concern is that the solution provided is based on the *average pressure and temperature* in the regions whereas the pressure at the face of the piston will be considerably higher at the front face and lower on the rear face, resulting in a different force calculations.
At this stage I am looking for a way to determine the nature of the curve and thus the realistic value for the force.